# NodeJS: writing JSON file not having line breaks when i open in Notepad. But is pretty view with other Editors

Tags: notepad, newlines, json, linebreaks

I am writing a JSON file using NodeJS, like this:

```
var path = "D:\\test.json"
var writeContent = {"Success" : "This is a sample"}
fs.writeFile(path, JSON.stringify(writeContent, null, 4), function (error) {
        if (error === null) {
            response.json(SuccessResponse);
        }else{
            response.json(ErrorResponse + error.message);
        }
    });
```

The file is getting written successfully, and also the JSON file is pretty printed when I open the JSON file in latest file editors such as Subllime3, Notepad++ I am able to view the pretty form of the file.  But when I open the same file in Notepad, I am not able to view the content in the pretty format.

It is viewed as:

```
{    "GlobalName": "CIRCULAR_GRATES_M01_METRIC",    "LocalName": "Circular Grates M01"    }
```

Comment: Related from SO: [Node.JS constant for platform-specific new line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864486/node-js-constant-for-platform-specific-new-line)

Answer (score 4):

The file most likely has UNIX line breaks (`\n`), as opposed to Windows line breaks (`\r\n`). Notepad is rather dumb and only supports the latter.

Wordpad, on the other hand, supports both. This is not a joke. ;)

Most “modern” editors support both and allow conversion between the two (and possibly Mac line breaks).

Comment: Since 2001, Mac OS X line breaks are Unix line breaks, `0x0a` aka `\n` aka `LF`. (OS 9 and earlier used `0x0d` aka `\r` aka `CR`.)